# How to resolve mypy [arg-type] error with generic function as argument?

Tags: python, mypy

I want to give a generic function as argument into another function (called `apply`) associated with a type. The typing of the generic function should determine the type of the output.

Using a generic function with the signature `(T) -> T` with a `TypeVar` T, and a specific `apply` with signature `((float) -> T, float) -> T`, I get a `mypy` error:

```
Argument 1 to "apply" has incompatible type "Callable[[T], T]"; expected "Callable[[float], T]"  [arg-type]
```

How can I get a working typing?

In the following see a minimal example that should show the problem. The function `fa` does not work, whereas `fb` works...

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, List, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")

class C(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, val: T):
        self.val: T = val

    def apply(self, fn: Callable[[T], U]) -> U:
        return fn(self.val)

class FloatC(C[float]):
    pass

def fa(x: T) -> T:
    return x

def fb(x: T) -> str:
    return "hello"

c = FloatC(1)

a = c.apply(fa)
b = c.apply(fb)

reveal_type(a)
reveal_type(b)
```

The output of mypy is:

```
test.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "apply" of "C" has incompatible type "Callable[[T], T]"; expected "Callable[[float], T]"  [arg-type]
test.py:28: note: Revealed type is "T`-1"
test.py:29: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I would expect that mypy understands that `a` is a float and raises no error. What is wrong here and how can I solve it?

Comment: Change this fn: Callable[[T], U]) to fn: Callable[[T, U])

Comment: Inheriting from a concrete type does not seem to work well with inheritance. The revealed type of `c.apply` indicates that `T` is in fact narrowed to `float`, but the actual call to `c.apply` still seems to require the more general type of `C.apply`.

Comment: If you add a type hint `a: float = c.apply(fa)`, you'll get an additional error indicating the type of `ca.apply(fa)` is `T`, not `float` as required by the target.